# Facebook API - FB.api() call works but AJAX request does not

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, permissions

I have an issue where I make a request as:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
        });
```

And the request succeeds. However, when I manually do the call via AJAX to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100000673883864/me?access_token=CAAIqk2q3UU8BAMZ…xj6wOEy0gHNsvK9JoeE9uYsSDSOZAcOJO0x9igOyhuCkm2lfKkVsta5tW1KOurvphX2zzR4sZD
```

I got a 400 and an error saying Invalid OAuth Token.

Any idea why?

EDIT: As pointed out below, my URL was wrong, but when changed it to:
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=CAAIqk2q3UU8BACY0xPINOHdPIlnaJRo…irkbv78kVQu0okuXl89DIma0QXWzFEKTWtVRISypgkIrsv9MKdKljI3vNnvXRZBNbUJmzkcwZD

It still doesn't work. Debugging the token, I get a valid token:
Issued: Unknown
Expires: 1376852400 (in about an hour)
Valid:  True
Origin: Web
Scopes: create_note photo_upload publish_actions publish_stream share_item status_update video_upload

EDIT #2:
I've now gotten it to the point where I get this error: "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action" but I thought /me was the most basic of calls - that I didn't need an extra permission/scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... was b/c I was doing a POST not a GET.

Comment: what do you mean? if you put in the call like that in the browser, it´s GET

Comment: as I said above, I was doing it in AJAX

Answer (score 0):

First, you can debug every Token here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

But that´s not the problem in this case. You included your id AND /me:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My URL was indeed wrong but I still get the same OAuthException when I corrected it (see edit above)